# What's the best wordpress desktop client on Linux

Tags: linux, blogging

I'm doing a bit weblogging these days and wordpress is my host of choice. But I don't like the editing interface of it. So I'm looking for a Linux desktop client. Would like something that's simple and effective and based on GTK as I use Xubuntu.

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research.

Answer (score 2):

First, WordPress 3.8 comes with a new interface that maybe easier for you to live with. And you can always use a text editor to compose your post, copy that over to WordPress, make some necessary adjustments and publish it.

Second, try to live with the web interface as WordPress updates regularly and you never know if your desktop client will work tomorrow.

Finally, to the point of your question, you can compose the post in your favorite email editor and [send it over](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_to_your_blog_using_email) to WordPress. Hope that this helps.